# ASP.NET up down scroll dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I'm currently making a registration form, and I want the users to select their birthday month, using a dropdownlist. However, I want to make it so that there is both and up and down button for them to select their month (like google's sign up form as seen in the picture below)[image]

I only can make a dropdown list with the down button, but how would I go about if I want an up button so that for e.g when the user is at February they'll press ^ and go back to January?

Answer (score 1):

That is not an `ASP.Net` control, that is something like [Jquery UI Spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) with up-down buttons and arrow key handling,
you can also use [this](http://codepen.io/Thibaut/pen/Jasci) or [this](http://marcj.github.io/jquery-selectBox/)
or if they are not appropriate for you then you can change their styles.

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use jQuery Datepicker. For example, 3 times for each textbox.